Dealing with rude Security Guard
I am in high school, graduating year, and joined the school last year. Since then, I had this security guard standing on school entrance, who happens to be off with people. Whenever I do a mistake, he is completely after me. As multiple examples:

Whenever I accidentally forget school card, he threatens and misbehaves with me. The same is not true for some students who enter in freely without any disruptions and pleasingly welcome them.

If students are late at leaving time and have to remain at least one hour beyond the school time, girls are to remain in campus and boys are literally kicked from school to get out. This security guard goes as far as grabbing and pushing people including me. This is not true for students who have some 'good' relations with the security guard. Is this even how a school should do?

Recently I was an hour late, but in Career Advisor office who stopped me to discuss my further future plans, after school leaving time. We sat for an hour to talk about the places I want to apply. As soon as I came outside to leave, this man started shouting, like actual roaring at me that where I was? Is this really how a security guard should be concerned? Regarding this, I told him that I was in Career Advisor office, and he roared again: Manage your time inside. I am literally impressed...


What I tried till date is:

Talk to my parents. I told my father about his certain misdemeanor but my father has said that he is in poor working conditions and rude because of certain problems. I will not agree to this because he is nice with certain set of people (who are complete bullies, enter school freely and harass people, or certain people who have been in this school from long time)

Talked to school psychologist. Busy psychologist who has only recommended me to just ignore him. Tried this multiple times to not even look at the guard but whenever I am in problem, like the leaving time issue, I cannot ignore him


What I want is:

A way that this guard just leaves me alone. I know I am not the only one person with whom he is rude but I really want him just to spare me and remain with me only professional.


Beside your parents and the school psy, did you think of talking to the headmaster, director or any deputy in charge? I mean, in many countries, there's an organization chart with someone in charge of such problems. BTW, what country are you from?

@OldPadawan I chose not to, but I have a reason for that. Last year I was bullied and beaten up by some bullies, administration had apparent no proof of assault on me (even with visible marks on my face). Instead they literally asked my parents to have my psychological evaluation done. Apart from this, my father had told me not to talk to my Principal apparently because to him the issue does not look too serious

You have a goal, but your post doesn't make it clear what part of your interpersonal skills you're asking about, what part of them you're struggling with to reach said goal. Without that, this post is just a general question about what to do, instead of a specific question about interpersonal skills.

Every action you take has a chance of improving or deteriorating things. If this guy wants to cause you trouble, how much trouble can he cause you? How much trouble can you cause him?
